# Linq query for searching an object inside a dictionary having list of lists as values

Tags: c#, linq

I'm searching a sorted dictionary with a key of type datetime and values as list of objects. What I need to find is the latest value(based on a property on the object) for each object in the dictionary. My object has 3 properties : a name, a value and a date when it was created. My dictionary is sorted by latest date in descending order.

I have got this working somehow, but I'm sure there is a shortcut for this using LINQ. Please note that I'm using **.NET 3.5**. Could you please help? Please dont get put off by the huge amount code below as I have added it for clarity and i'm only looking for a linq query to query inside a list of list objects.

Code below:

```
public void Should_link_recent_data_together()
{
    var data = TimeSeriesDataFactoryEx.GetData();

    var allAttributes = new List<string>()
    {
        TimeSeriesConstants.TOTAL_COST_CODE,
        TimeSeriesConstants.TOTAL_VALUE_CODE,
        TimeSeriesConstants.SOURCE_CODE
    };

    var latestList = new List<TimeSeries>();

    var allValues = data.Values.ToList();


    #region HOW DO I DO THIS USING LINQ?

    bool found = false;

    foreach (var attribute in allAttributes)
    {
        found = false;
        foreach (var tsData in allValues)
        {
            foreach (var ts in tsData)
            {
                if (ts.MetricName == attribute && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ts.MetricValue))
                {
                    latestList.Add(ts);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    Assert.IsTrue(latestList.Count == 3);
    Assert.IsTrue(latestList.Where(x => x.MetricName == TimeSeriesConstants.TOTAL_COST_CODE).First().MetricValue == "1");
    Assert.IsTrue(latestList.Where(x => x.MetricName == TimeSeriesConstants.TOTAL_VALUE_CODE).First().MetricValue == "2");
    Assert.IsTrue(latestList.Where(x => x.MetricName == TimeSeriesConstants.SOURCE_CODE).First().MetricValue == "gp");
    Assert.IsTrue(latestList.Where(x => x.MetricName == TimeSeriesConstants.SOURCE_CODE).First().Quarter == DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3));

}



internal class TimeSeriesDataFactoryEx
{
    public static SortedDictionary<DateTime?,List<TimeSeries>> GetData()
    {
        return new SortedDictionary<DateTime?, List<TimeSeries>>(new DateComparer())
        {
            {
                DateTime.Today, new List<TimeSeries>()
                {
                    new TimeSeries()
                    {
                        Quarter = DateTime.Today,
                        MetricValue = "1",
                        MetricName = TimeSeriesConstants.TOTAL_COST_CODE
                    },
                    new TimeSeries()
                    {
                        Quarter = DateTime.Today,
                        MetricValue = "2",
                        MetricName = TimeSeriesConstants.TOTAL_VALUE_CODE
                    },
                    new TimeSeries()
                    {
                        Quarter = DateTime.Today,
                        MetricValue = "",
                        MetricName = TimeSeriesConstants.SOURCE_CODE
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3), new List<TimeSeries>()
                {
                    new TimeSeries()
                    {
                        Quarter = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3),
                        MetricValue = "3",
                        MetricName = TimeSeriesConstants.TOTAL_COST_CODE
                    },
                    new TimeSeries()
                    {
                        Quarter = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3),
                        MetricValue = "4",
                        MetricName = TimeSeriesConstants.TOTAL_VALUE_CODE
                    },
                    new TimeSeries()
                    {
                        Quarter = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3),
                        MetricValue = "gp",
                        MetricName =TimeSeriesConstants.SOURCE_CODE
                    }
                }
                }

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should indent your code a little bit more, We can still see some of your code without scrolling right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming I understand your question right, say you have a dictionary like so:

```
{ Key = "1/1/1900", Value = List Of Objects, of which each has a DateTimeProperty }
...
{ Key = "1/4/1900", Value = List Of Objects, of which each has a DateTimeProperty }
```

And you are looking to find a set of objects from your dictionary, where it's the latest by time of each key, then you can do this pretty simply with linq:

```
var latestItems = data.SelectMany(kvp => 
    kvp.Value.OrderByDescending(value => value.Quarter).Take(1)
);
```

This query finds the most recent object in each bucket and then returns that as a single set (not an enumerable of enumerables). You can change the selector inside the `SelectMany` to find elements in each set as much as you want, as long as you return an `IEnumerable` from that callback.